# Wordpress add post_class to page sections when shown on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, class, post

I am trying to build a single page wordpress theme. I've been able to display all my pages content on one page and scroll between it using menu items. Now I want to add the `<?php post_class(); ?>` to each of my page sections so they show the proper wordpress classes.

Here is my php that outputs all of the page contents into one page,

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
$slug = $page_data->post_name;
$class = post_class('content_wrapper');
echo '<div id="' . $slug . '" class="' . $class . '">';
echo $content;
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

There are 2 issues with this code that I can't seem to resolve:

1) This code just outputs the same class for each page, not different classes for each page

2) The class is just outputted into my raw HTML so is visable on my site - it's not adding into where i've written `class="' . $class . '">';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$class = get_post_class('content_wrapper', $page_data->ID);
printf ( '<div id="%s" class="%s">', $slug, implode(' ', $class) );
```

`post_class()` is designed to `echo` the resulting class. `get_post_class()` returns the post classes as an array.

Since you're operating outside the loop, you need to manually pass the post ID to the function.

Comment: That worked great. Just a thought. Do you know how I would add the post ID into the ID of the div?

Comment: Sure. Try something like this: `$slug = $page_data->post_name . '-' . $page_data->ID;`